# Creating a Grails catch-all URL-mapping

Tags: grails, url-rewriting

**How do I create a catch-all URL-mapping in Grails?**

The following Grails UrlMapping ..

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/$something"{
      controller = "something"
      action = "something"
    }
  }
}
```

.. appears to match `^/[^/]*` but how do I create an UrlMapping matching all URLs (`^/.*`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the ** "double wildcard".  Example:

```
   class UrlMappings {
      static mappings = {
        "/**"(controller: "something", action: "something")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! One remaining question - how do I obtain the matched string - that is the value of /**?

Comment: Found the answer: "/$something**" gives me params.something - thanks!

Comment: I did this and now my when going to `/` via `createLink` my URL looks like `http://<host>/**`

Comment: To be safe, best to put the catchall as the last entry in UrlMappngs